# Intersection of Excel Columns in Respect to a Third Column

Tags: excel

Suppose I have 3 columns in my excel file that look like this:

Column A has the values {A,B,C,...,Z} (each value is a cell down the row)

Column B has the values {www.link.com/A/browse.html,...,www.link.com/Z/browse.html}

Column C has the values {A,1,B,2,D,5,78,...Z,54}

That is, column A doesn't contain C and neither does C contain A, but they do have common values, and column B has the values of A within a link.

I need to get all the rows of B so that their "name", A,B,..,Z, in my example, appears in column C and of course in A (the intersection of both columns, but yielding the link from column B).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the link part in column B constant, so that you can extract the "A", "B", etc. with a substring expression?

Comment: @TToni Hey,
Yes, kind of, but for example; in column A I may have "Product Name" but in B will have www.search.com/search/product-name/888999

Answer (score 0):

Add another column with `=IF(A1=C1;B1;"")`. This column will contain all values of column B where A and C are equal, with empty cells in between.

If you don't want to have empty cells in between, write `=IF(A1=C1;1;"")`, then filter for values of 1 in that column.